# Using postcss with autoprefixer and geting the error - 'cannot find module'

Tags: npm, postcss, autoprefixer, npm-scripts

I am trying to add prefixes using npm scripts.

here is the npm script that i am using

```
postcss --use autoprefixer prodapp/css/sass.css -d prodapp/css/
```

On their git hub page also they have shown the same command.
https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer#cli

This is the error i am getting

```
x Plugin Error: Cannot find module 'prodapp/css/sass.css'
```

Comment: The link you provided shows the arguments in a different order. Try: `postcss prodapp/css/sass.css --use autoprefixer -d prodapp/css/`

Comment: Thanks bro. That worked. You can add it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Robc's suggestion worked for me. The correct script should follow the sequence as follows

```
postcss prodapp/css/sass.css --use autoprefixer -d prodapp/css/
```